# scrolltop within a div is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate `scrolltop` with in a div when I animate body scroll it is working fine for me

But when I am using it with in a `div` it's fails.

**This is working fine for me
http://jsfiddle.net/yazaLyxs/**

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#myId').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

**Then why this code is not working ?**

```
$('.myClass').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#myId').offset().top
}, 'slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qVWuv/198/

Comment: Has your `.myClass` element scrollbar? Does it contain `#myId` element?

Comment: yes myClass have a scrollbar and i am using mtId within myClass

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qVWuv/199/ This is working fine here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK since no-one answered exactly about what's all about:

**`.position().top` does not take into account an element's margin.** ***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/qVWuv/203/)***

---

Your first example might work in Chrome, but not in Firefox, cause of the slight differences in `documentElement`.

To account for it you'll have to use:

```
$('html, body').animate({
```

Now, let's look the difference between Methods `.position()` and `.offset()`:

**[.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/)**

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.

**[.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)**

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

if the above is clear, and you want to get the inner `child` element position **inside a positioned parent<sup>*</sup>**, you'll need to use `.position()`.

```
#parent {
    height: 300px;
    background: teal;
    margin: 500px 0 0 0;
    overflow:scroll;
    position:relative; /* NEEDED! */
}
```

Now, you might have set the inner's element margin to `500px` but it's **top position** is still **`0`** px!

```
console.log( $('#child').position().top ); // 0
```

therefore you need to set a `top:` style (instead of `margin`) and `position:` to the `#save` element in order to use `$('#child').position().top`: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/qVWuv/203/ ***(or at least put some other elements before it or some content).***

<sub>*If you don't set a "position:" CSS property to the parent element you need to subtract the parent's top position or offset.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**if in html**

```
<div class="myClass">
    <label></label>
    <label id="myId">target Label</label>
</div>
```

**and in css**

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

in js

```
$('.myClass').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#myId').position().top
}, 'slow');
```

everything should work .. [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7govk2dr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#myId').position().top
}, 'slow');
```

This working fine becauase you set div at margin-top:500px; that make vertical scroll into picture over body.

So you need a DOM element having enough height to get a vertical scroll, please note this element is parent element not the target element i.e. tag which contains your div.

Check this [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaLyxs/2/)